# Sharding pattern with Nhibernate and Azure Blob for Binary

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, azure-blob-storage, sharding

I'm actually develop a website with ASP.Net MVC with NHibernate.

You can found a Sample of the base of the solution I use on GitHub:  [Pixel.Sample](https://github.com/Nono31/Pixel.Sample)

I have Repository for picture to manage NHibernate Microsoft SQL entity.
My PictureManager call my PictureRepository to Save() it.
I want to shard my Binary for picture and thunbail in Azure CloudStorage blob, so I didn't map the Binary Field on my ClassMap, but how to catch my Save Update Delete in my current architecture to save only Binary in different support (CloudStorage)

Actually I'm trying to found a solution for this, any ideas ?

**UPDATE**

After the relevant answer from Pelican, I think I'll use [LazyLoad](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363571/Remote-Lazy-Loading-in-Hibernate) with Proxy to load Binary and Interceptor to save / update / delete

Take a look to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36555880/5552501)

Comment: Have you seen [this](/q/14436050/1178314)?

Comment: Yes Frederic, but this case is to shard in SQL only, in my case i want my shard in AzureBlobStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NHibernate events](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html),

```
public class TestInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor {

    private int updates;
    private int creates;
    private int loads;

    public override void OnDelete(object entity,
                                  object id,
                                  object[] state,
                                  string[] propertyNames,
                                  IType[] types)
    {
    }

    public override bool OnFlushDirty(object entity, 
                                      object id, 
                      object[] currentState,
                      object[] previousState, 
                      string[] propertyNames,
                      IType[] types) 
    {
    }

    public override bool OnLoad(object entity, 
                                object id, 
                object[] state, 
                string[] propertyNames, 
                IType[] types)
    {
    }

    public override bool OnSave(object entity, 
                                object id, 
                object[] state, 
                string[] propertyNames, 
                IType[] types)
    {
    }

    public override void AfterTransactionCompletion(ITransaction tx)
    {
        if ( tx.WasCommitted ) {
        }
    }
}
```

and you can register it,

```
new Configuration().SetInterceptor( new TestInterceptor() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Pelican to help me on this answer, i just found what i want:

**NHibernate.Proxy.DynamicProxy.ProxyFactory**

On IInterceptor.Instance, you should choose wich class you want to put proxy

```
    public override Object Instantiate(String clazz, EntityMode entityMode, Object id)
    {
        if (entityMode == EntityMode.Poco)
        {
            Type type = Type.GetType(clazz, false);

            if (type != null)
            {
                Object instance = CreateProxy(type);

                this.session.SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(clazz).SetIdentifier(instance, id, entityMode);

                return (instance);
            }
        }

        return (base.Instantiate(clazz, entityMode, id));
    }


    public static Object CreateProxy(Type type)
    {
        List<Type> interfaces = new List<Type>();
        //TODO: add interfaces to list
        interfaces.Add(typeof(IBar));

        Object instance = null;

        if ((interfaces.Count != 0) && (type.IsSealed == false))
        {
            //TODO: pass any custom parameters to the _CustomInterceptor class
            instance = proxyGenerator.CreateProxy(type, new CustomPictureInterceptor(), interfaces.ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }

        return (instance);
    }
```

And on Intercept method you can do what you want:

```
  class CustomPictureInterceptor : NHibernate.Proxy.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor
    {
        public object Intercept(InvocationInfo info)
        {
            //Do what you want
            return info.InvokeMethodOnTarget();
        }
    }
```

References:

http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/nhibernate-interceptor-for-dynamic-proxy-generation

http://kozmic.net/2011/03/20/working-with-nhibernate-without-default-constructors/